# Custom javascript function doesn't work with PrettyCheckable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom javascript function to check and uncheck all the checkboxs in my form. Then I added PrettyCheckable and now the custom function doesn't work. Here is the code.

```
<a onclick="javascript:checkAll('nameform', true);" href="javascript:void();">check all</a>
<a onclick="javascript:checkAll('nameform', false);" href="javascript:void();">check all</a>

<form method="POST" name="nameform">
   <div class="prettycheckbox labelright green">
     <input class="prettyCheckable" type="checkbox" name="checkboxs" data-label="{{skill}}" >
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">// <![CDATA[
function checkAll(formname, checktoggle)
{
  var checkboxes = new Array(); 
  checkboxes = document[formname].getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)  {
    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')   {
      checkboxes[i].checked = checktoggle;
    }
  }
}
// ]]></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.prettyCheckable').prettyCheckable()
</script>
```

Update:  trying to use the function from prettyCheckable but still it doesn't work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkAll(formname, checktoggle){
    if (checktoggle === true) {
       $('.prettyCheckable').prettyCheckable('check');
    } else {
        $('.prettyCheckable').prettyCheckable('uncheck');
    } 
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: you can't call function this way

Comment: @Girish What do you mean? Which one? I have two functions.

Comment: Why would you use an inline `onclick` handler when jQuery is at your disposal?

Answer (score 0):

At http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/ it says

> check OR uncheck   Um... well... it checks/unchecks the input.

You can use this code to check and uncheck the boxes after the prettyCheckable has been applied.

Comment: You should probably wrap it in $.each()